# Replacing a string in an R formula

Tags: r, scope, formula

I have a question about formula modification in R.

Lets say that I have a formula.

```
> fo <- a ~ b + c
```

I can substitute a term out using `substitute_q`

```
> pryr::substitute_q(fo, list(a = 'happy'))
"happy" ~ b + c
```

If I want to substitute a term in without quotation marks, I can substitute it in as a name

```
> pryr::substitute_q(fo, list(a = as.name('happy')))
happy ~ b + c
```

Now, however, lets say that I have a formula with a string.

```
> fo <- 'a' ~ b + c
> fo
"a" ~ b + c
```

I can't find a way to substitute the string out of the formula.

```
> pryr::substitute_q(fo, list(a = as.name('happy')))
"a" ~ b + c
> pryr::substitute_q(fo, list("a" = as.name('happy')))
"a" ~ b + c
> pryr::substitute_q(fo, list(`"a"` = as.name('happy')))
"a" ~ b + c
> pryr::substitute_q(fo, list('"a"' = as.name('happy')))
"a" ~ b + c
```

I think this is because `substitute_q` looks for variables within an environment when performing substitutions, which means that it always tries to replace *names* within the formula. Is there a way to substitute out the character 'a'?

Comment: @d.b So this works for the specific case presented. For a more complicated one like: `func1(a, b) ~ func2("e", 10) + b * c + func3(d)`I find `reformulate` is lacking. Can it be adapted for a complicated case like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In base R, use `deparse` to convert formula to character, carry out the necessary substitution, and coerce back to formula

```
fo <- 'a' ~ b + c
as.formula(gsub("\"a\"", "\"happy\"", deparse(fo)))
#"happy" ~ b + c

fo2 = func1(a, b) ~ func2("e", 10) + b * c + func3(d)
as.formula(gsub("func2(\"e\", 10)", "func2(HAN, SOLO)", deparse(fo2), fixed = TRUE))
#func1(a, b) ~ func2(HAN, SOLO) + b * c + func3(d)
```